# I don't understand this class-related error in python

Tags: python, class, self

i'm a beginner and this code is not working and I don't understand why.
i think I'm doing something wrong with the use of "self" but I'm not sure.

```
import turtle as t

class Carre:
    def __init__(self,x,y,lg,col):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.lg=lg
        self.col=col

    def tracer(self,lg):
        for i in range(4):
            t.forward(self.lg)
            t.right(90)

    def carre(self,x,y,lg,col):
        t.speed=0
        t.penup()
        t.hideturtle()
        t.goto(x,y)
        t.pendown()
        t.fillcolor(col)
        t.begin_fill()
        self.tracer(lg)
        t.end_fill()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *class-related error in python* what error did you get?

Comment: + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument

Comment: First of all, fix the indentation in the constructor.

Comment: My bad, i pasted the code but the indetation is correct in the ide

Comment: That error looks like a Powershell error, which is surprising since you seem to be writing Python. Can you tell us how you entered and ran this code?

Comment: I'm on the latest version of visual studio code with python3.10.0, i executed the code as I do normally, with "run python file in terminal".

Comment: What is the filename of your code? Does it end with `.ps` instead of `.py`?

Comment: To clarify, the code compile but return this error when i type "Carre.carre(self,100,100,100,'red')". It returns the error " + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Carre.carre:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException" when i do "Carre.carre(100,100,100,'red')" instead.

Comment: It end with .py

Comment: @Papaya did you type `Carre.carre(self,100,100,100,'red')` in the Terminal? That won't do; Terminal is PowerShell.

Comment: @pepoluan i tried that but with edupython, that i believe don't use terminal, the same error is displayed. Anyway, what do I have to type instead ?

Comment: @Papaya you have to write a complete Python program instead, and tell VSCode to execute it. As it is now, your program is not complete; it only contains definition of one class and no instructions to execute. Please find a tutorial on writing Python programs first.

Comment: Okay thanks for your time, i'll try to find one that I understand.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to pass self variables into functions. Please look into my code

```
import turtle as t

class Carre:
    def __init__(self,x,y,lg,col):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.lg=lg
        self.col=col
        # self.carre(x, y, lg, col)

    def tracer(self):
        for i in range(4):
            t.forward(self.lg)
            t.right(90)

    def carre(self):
        t.speed=0
        t.penup()
        t.hideturtle()
        t.goto(self.x, self.y)
        t.pendown()
        t.fillcolor(self.col)
        t.begin_fill()
        self.tracer()
        t.end_fill()
        t.mainloop()
        
Carre(10, 10, 10, 'red').carre()
```